# How do I convert an excel table to a JSON array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, javascript, data-transfer

I need to enter large amount of data in an array, which will be in this form:

```
[
  [data1,data2,data3,...,data9],
  [data1,data2,data3,...,data9],
  [data1,data2,data3,...,data9],
  ...
]
```

As it stands, entering the data directly as JSON is a time consuming process that tends to have many errors. Alternatively, I would like to enter the data into an excel sheet and generate the JSON array from the sheet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is an operation that you would do once or a few times only,
here is a zero-work solution, using the website
[Mr. Data Converter](https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/),
apparently created by a Shan Carter.

Here is how I converted this dummy sample spreadsheet of 679 duplicated rows :

[image: spreadsheet]

1. Select the entire data using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Copy to the clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Open the website [Mr. Data Converter](https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/)
4. Click in the upper text area and paste-in the data with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
5. Select Output as "JSON - Row Arrays"
6. The result in the lower text area will look like :

[image]

7. Click in the lower text area and it will be selected
8. Copy to the clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

You may now paste the data anywhere and add around it the declaration
for the JavaScript array.

Note for the future : If the Mr. Data Converter website ever disappears from the Internet,
a working copy of it can be found on the
[Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180628080610/https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/), which is a JavaScript tool to parse .csv files.

First, input all your data to Excel, and save the file as a .csv

Next use NPM to install Papa Parse:

```
$ npm install papaparse
```

Import your .csv to JS:

```
var file = '/path/to/your.csv';

var content = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
```

Then use this code to parse the .csv to an array:

```
var Papa = require('papaparse');

Papa.parse(content, {
    header: false,
    delimiter: "\t",
    complete: function(results) {
    rows = results.data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [Mr Data Converter](http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) as well for a while, but it lacks with missing support of quotes, commas line brakes etc. and the last update was 6 years ago.

Imho a pretty good alternative is [convertcsv.com](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm)
It has great features (especially considering line brakes, if you take the data easily from an XLS per copy&paste).

For the record from their privacy policy:

> We do not collect data inputted or outputted via our conversion
> services.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `,` as delimiter in a plain-text `.csv` file you can simply do this:

```js
var csvarray = [];
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/mydata.csv');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var rows = client.responseText.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        csvarray.push(rows[i].split(','));
    }
}
client.send();
```

`csvarray` will contain one array per row of the csv, containing it's comma-separated data.